# How can I fix '"HPDM.framework" will damage your computer' on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, printing, big-sur, driver, certificate

Since updating to macOS Big Sur, I can no longer print to my HP DeskJet 1010 printer. Each time that I start a print job, I get a dialog with error message that says '"HPDM.framework" will damage your computer'. There is no way to bypass the warning in 'System Preferences' -> 'Security & Privacy' as there might be with applications that have expired or invalid developer certificates.

N.B. I did find a workaround that involved removing the printer from 'System Preferences' -> 'Printers & Scanners' then adding it again with generic print drivers, but this blocked me from using some of the features I typically use, such as printing with just the black cartridge.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404993/hp-easy-scan-hp-scanner-3-will-damage-your-computer and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404944/stopping-false-positive-malware-warnings-in-catalina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much trial and error, I was finally able to get my HP DeskJet 1010 printer working again with the following steps:

1. Download and run the [HP Uninstaller app](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06960563)
2. Download and install [HP Printer Drivers v5.1 for macOS](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1888?locale=en_US)
3. Open 'System Preferences' -> 'Printers & Scanners', right-click the box labeled 'Printers' and select 'Reset printing system...' (if you have more than one printer, you may want to remove just the non-functioning profile by selecting it and clicking the '-' button).
4. Click the '+' button to add a new printer, select 'HP DeskJet Series', and follow the prompts.

It is my suspicion that this will work with other HP printers affected by their revoked developer certificate.

Comment: Please note that for newer devices, it is HP Easy Start or Easy Admin that should be used for reinstalling the drivers after deinstallation. The whole procedure is described in the https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06960563 knowledge base article. I was reluctant to use the HP Uninstaller application, as it claims to remove “*all* configured devices,” but it turned out that it leaves all non-HP devices untouched. (At least the several non-HP printers that I had in my configuration were still there after running the uninstaller.)